# Text fields with finite domain: to factor into sub-tables or not?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, database-normalization

A new database is to store the log data of a (series of) web servers.  The structure of the log records has been converted to this ‘naïve’ general schema:

```
CREATE TABLE log (
    matchcode SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    stamp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    ip INET,
    bytes NUMERIC,
    vhost TEXT,
    path TEXT,
    user_agent TEXT,
    -- and so on
);
```

And so on, there are many more fields, but this shows the general principle.  The bulk of the data are contained in free-text fields as shows above.  Of course, this will make the database rather big in the long run.  We are talking about a web server log, so this doesn’t come as a big surprise.

The domain of those text fields is limited, though.  There is e.g. a very finite set of vhosts that will be seen, a much larger, but still decidedly finite set of paths, user agents and so on.  In cases like this, would it be more appropriate to factor the text fields out into sub-tables, and reference them only via identifiers?  I am thinking along a line like this:

```
CREATE TABLE vhost ( ident SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, vhost TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE );
CREATE TABLE path ( ident SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, path TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE );
CREATE TABLE user_agent ( ident SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, user_agent TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE );

CREATE TABLE log (
    matchcode SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    stamp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    ip INET,
    bytes NUMERIC,
    vhost INTEGER REFERENCES vhost ( ident ) ,
    path INTEGER REFERENCES path ( ident ),
    user_agent INTEGER REFERENCES user_agent ( ident ),
    -- and so on
);
```

I have tried both approaches now.  As expected, the second one is much smaller, by give or take factor three.  However, *querying* it becomes significantly slower due to all the joins involved.  The difference is by about an order of magnitude.

From what I understand, the table should be sufficiently normal in both cases.  At some later point in the project, there’ll maybe be additional attributes attached to the various text values (like additional information about each vhost and so on).

The practical considerations are obvious, it’s basically a space/time tradeoff.  In the long run, what is considered best practice in such a case?  Are there other, perhaps more theoretical implications for such a scenario that I might want to be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

> The domain of those text fields is limited, though. There is e.g. a
>   very finite set of vhosts that will be seen, a much larger, but still
>   decidedly finite set of paths, user agents and so on. In cases like
>   this, would it be more appropriate to factor the text fields out into
>   sub-tables, and reference them only via identifiers?

There are a couple of different ways to look at this kind of problem. Regardless of which way you look at it, *appropriate* is a fuzzy word.

**Constraints**

Let's imagine that you create a table and a foreign key constraint to allow the "vhost" column to accept only five values. Can you also constrain the web server to *write* only those five values to the log file? No, you can't.

You *can* add some code to insert new virtual hosts into into the referenced table. You can even automate that with triggers. But when you do that, you're no longer *constraining* the values for "vhost". This remains true whether you use natural keys or surrogate keys.

**Data compression with ID numbers**

You can also think of this as a problem of data compression. You save space--potentially a *lot* of space--by using integers as foreign keys to tables of unique text. You might *not* save time. Queries that require a lot of joins are often slower than queries that just read data directly. You've already seen that.

---

In your case, which has to do with machine-generated log files, I prefer to store them as they come from the device (web server, flow sensor, whatever) unless there's a compelling reason not to.

In a few cases, I've worked on systems where domain experts have determined that certain kinds of values shouldn't be transferred from a log file to a database. For example, domain experts might decide that negative numbers from a sensor means the sensor is broken. This kind of constraint is better handled with a CHECK() constraint, but the principle is the same.

*Take what the device gives you unless there's a compelling reason not to.*